# what does this type of define do with a && in it

Tags: c-preprocessor

Im not familiar with this type of define, need help on what does line 5 do? does it redefined AND_CPU_0?

```
#ifdef CONDITION_1
#define AND_CPU_0
#define AND_CPU_1
#ifdef CONDITION_2
#define AND_CPU_0 && [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 0] 
#endif
#ifdef CONDITION_3
#define AND_CPU_1 && [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 1]
#endif

#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should this question be tagged `C` if it only refer to the C preprocessor ? There is a tag `c-preprocessor` but I don't know if it's really relevant...

Answer (score 2):

`#define AND_CPU_0 && [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 0]`  just defines `AND_CPU_0` to be `&& [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 0]`.

For example, in the source code you can have

```
if (enable == true AND_CPU_0) {

}
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (enable == true && [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 0]) {

}
```

Comment: Note that `enable == true` may not be the best example of an average Boolean test :).

Comment: True. Just added `== true` for visuality.

Comment: ok. so basically '&& [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 0]' is one thing, and if will be #define AND_CPU_0 something.

Comment: you use `&&` just for shortcut. you could always exclude `&&` from definition and then include in statements. eg. `if statement`

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor simply substitutes macro invocation with the body of the macro.

In this case, if you have a shell-script with a statement like this:

```
if [ something AND_CPU_0 ]; then ... fi
```

it will simply be replaced with

```
if [ something && [ $(get_id cpu) -ne 0] ]; then ... fi
```

Comment: @Koushik This is obviously not a `C` example

Comment: @Koushik The preprocessor macros in the OPs post looks like POSIX (e.g. Unix, Linux, OSX) shell code, so I showed an example using shell `if` statements. Remember that the C preprocessor can be run as a standalone program (called `cpp` on many systems) to preprocess any text file.